# Memory issues when writing to file from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, memory

```
db.connect()
sentenceTB = sentenceTB.select()
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentenceTB):
    with open('./commentary/sentence%i.txt' %i, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(sentence.SNTENC)
db.close()
```

I use this code to connect to the database, select a table and write everything that is in that table to a separate file. The table has over 1 mln records and it was going great first, but when code started writing 900 000th record, the computer is slowed down very much. PyCharm is continuously asking me for allocating more memory to it and if first 500k records were done in 1 hour, now it takes him 1 hour to write 50-100 records.

I have thoughts that it should be somehow connected to releasing the memory, but I really don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to close the cursor?  It looks like you're opening a new one with each iteration, which would explain the lack of memory after a few hundred thousand iterations.

db.connect()
sentenceTB = sentenceTB.select()
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentenceTB):
    with open('./commentary/sentence%i.txt' %i, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(sentence.SNTENC)
    cursor.close()
db.close()

Comment: Sorry for not answering for so long. No, the cursor shouldn't be closed, I iterate over 1.7 mil entries at once. The solution was hard-coded: I copied this table to another table with automatic numeration row and started saving 1.7 mil entries in 5 iterations. This took me 3 days to complete, but I couldn't find better solution for that moment.